# Istio + Kubernetes: Gateway more than one TLS Certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, istio, gateway

I have a Kubernetes cluster with multiple tenants (in different namespaces). I'd like to deploy an independent Istio Gateway object into each tenant, which I seem to be able to do. However, setting up TLS requires a K8s secret that contains the TLS key/cert. The docs indicate that the "secret must be named istio-ingressgateway-certs in the istio-system namespace". This would seem to indicate that I can only have one TLS secret per cluster. Maybe I'm not reading this correctly. Is there a way to configure independent Istio Gateways in their own namespaces, with their own TLS secrets? How might I go about doing that?

Here is the doc that I'm referencing.
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but one ssl certificate can support more than one domain https://serverfault.com/q/391311/283777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As provided on [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-for-multiple-hosts) it's possible.

> In this section you will configure an ingress gateway for multiple hosts, httpbin.example.com and bookinfo.com.

So You need to create private keys, in this example, for [bookinfo](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/#create-a-server-certificate-and-private-key-for-bookinfo-com) and [httbin](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-mount/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-with-a-file-mount-based-approach), and update istio-ingressgateway.

I created them both and they exist.

bookinfo certs and gateway

```
kubectl exec -it -n istio-system $(kubectl -n istio-system get pods -l istio=ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -- ls -al /etc/istio/ingressgateway-bookinfo-certs

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Jan  3 10:12 tls.crt -> ..data/tls.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Jan  3 10:12 tls.key -> ..data/tls.key

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https-bookinfo
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-bookinfo-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-bookinfo-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "bookinfo.com"
```

---

httpbin certs and gateway

```
kubectl exec -it -n istio-system $(kubectl -n istio-system get pods -l istio=ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -- ls -al /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs


lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Jan  3 10:07 tls.crt -> ..data/tls.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Jan  3 10:07 tls.key -> ..data/tls.key


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: httpbin-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "httpbin.example.com"
```

Haven't made a full reproduction to check if they both works but if that won't work for You i will try to make it and update the question.

This [link](https://istiobyexample.dev/secure-ingress/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this great example and link.